# Is the phrase "if it had been for you" useable?

Tags: grammar

I tried looking for the answe in Google, but there was nothing.
Can I say if it had been for you as a snynom for If I had counted on you? And is it used by native English speakers?

Do these 2 sentences have the same meaning?

> - If I had counted on you, I would have been killed by now.
> - If it had been for you, I would have been killed now?

Comment: No. You can only use this construction in the *negative* - as, for example, *If it had **not** been for you I would have died* (the fact that I didn't die was only because of you or something you did, which I may or may not have been expecting and relying on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrasing feels a little clumsy even if it is an inversion of the phrase, 'If it hadn't been for you I'd have...'

I'd suggest that the phrasing in the second is on its surface synonymous with the first, but that it is an inversion of a more common phrase makes it sound wrong.

'If I had counted on you I'd be dead,' and 'I survived, no thanks to you,' may work a little more trippingly.

Comment: An answer on ELU needs supporting evidence. ' ... feels a little clumsy ...' shouldn't be awarded more than comment status.